# How to allow JRE to access itself?

Tags: java, securitymanager

So, I setup a custom `Policy` and enabled the `SecurityManager` and decided that I don't need any file permissions for my app.

But if I try to open a URL with the `https` protocol, I get this error:

```
access: access denied ("java.io.FilePermission" "jdk1.8.0/jre/lib/ext/amd64/libsunec.so" "read")

java.lang.Exception: Stack trace
    at java.lang.Thread.dumpStack(Thread.java:1329)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:447)
    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:884)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:549)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkRead(SecurityManager.java:888)
    at java.io.File.exists(File.java:814)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$ExtClassLoader.findLibrary(Launcher.java:222)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1820)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1119)
    at sun.security.ec.SunEC$1.run(SunEC.java:60)
    at sun.security.ec.SunEC$1.run(SunEC.java:58)
```

So, some class within the JRE is not able to load a native library because it doesn't get the file read permission.

Is there a good way to setup a permissive policy for JDK's own classes?

Comment: make sure the user you are using to start your Java application can execute the file in question

Comment: @Sebastian This error comes from Java, not the operating system.

Comment: Paging @Chris-Dennis : Any suggestions? :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is no way to separate the permissions for JDK from the permissions for *my* code. Both of them are loaded by the "null" class loader, so both get the same permissions. If there is a better way, please let me know.

Right now I am allowing this permission for the null-class loader:

```
final String recursiveSuffix = File.separator + "-";
final String javaPath = System.getProperty("java.home") + recursiveSuffix;
new FilePermission(javaPath, "read,execute");
```